# Rename path without renaming resources (models etc)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

I have a big feature called 'press releases'.

Client wants URL to say `/updates` rather than `/press_releases`.

Basic CRUD.

Is it possible to change the URL without renaming everything?

For example, when I say `resources_path` - is it possible to make it generate link `/updates` ?

Routes look like this:

```
resources :press_releases, except: :new  do
  collection do
    post 'sort'
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a combination of options to do this.

The `controller` option allows you to specify a controller to use for the routes, and the `as` option allows you to rename the helpers.

So, something like this should work:

```
resources :updates, controller: 'press_releases', as: 'press_releases', except: :new  do
  collection do
    post 'sort'
  end
end
```

Comment: very nice.. saved me few hours :)

Answer (score 0):

Sure,

```
resources :press_releases, :path => "/updates", except: :new  do
  collection do
    post 'sort'
  end
end
```

Comment: The generated paths are the same. The URL is different.